# Tengo un problema al levantar el server php me sala este error

Tags: php, visual-studio, email, server, wamp

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "Username" on null in C:
simplemente estoy tratando de enviar un correo con localhost pero me dae se error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. El código va en texto y no en imagen. Y el error es un typo, en la línea en cuestión (15), $oMai**L** termina en una L mayúscula.

Answer (score 0):

En tu linea 15 de tu archivo enviar php tienes el error como te lo indica la página al no encontrar la propiedad al tener un resultado null pero si te fijas bien
es un error de sintaxis(cosas no escritas correctamente)

mientras en tu objeto tienes a

```
$oMail
```

en tu linea 15 tienes a `$oMaiL` con L mayúscula.

Recuerda que es case sensitive, no es lo mismo usar
`$oMail` a  `$oMaiL` incluso cuando son las mismas letras ya que sus bits no son los mismos

tu linea 15 debe ir así

```
$oMail->Username ="sebaslol.g@hotmail.com";
```